# Data is getting embedded via a local json file

Tags: altair

I'm trying to plot some data, that data is in a pandas dataframe `cdfs`:

```
alt.Chart(cdfs).mark_line().encode(
    x = alt.X('latency:Q', scale=alt.Scale(type='log'), axis=alt.Axis(format="", title='Response_time (ms)')),
    y = alt.Y('percentile:Q', axis=alt.Axis(format="", title='Cumulative Fraction')),
    color='write_size:N',
)
```

The issue is that when viewing the source of the resultant plot there is just a url to a json file. That json file can't be found and hence the plots are appearing to be blank (no data).

```
{
  "config": {"view": {"continuousWidth": 400, "continuousHeight": 300}},
  "data": {
    "url": "altair-data-78b044f23db74f7d4408fba9f31b9ea9.json",
    "format": {"type": "json"}
  },
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "color": {"type": "nominal", "field": "write_size"},
    "x": {
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": {"format": "", "title": "Response_time (ms)"},
      "field": "latency",
      "scale": {"type": "log"}
    },
    "y": {
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": {"format": "", "title": "Cumulative Fraction"},
      "field": "percentile"
    }
  },
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.8.1.json"
}
```

This code was previously working (displaying the data on the chart) however I restarted the jupyterlab server its running on between now and then.

Hence I'm wondering why the data is getting embedded via a url rather than directly all of a sudden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point in your session, you must have run

```
alt.data_transformers.enable('json')
```

If you want to restore the default data transformer which embeds data directly into the chart, run

```
alt.data_transformers.enable('default')
```

Comment: This is to by default allow for large datasets I take it?

Comment: It is one way to allow larger datasets; see https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/faq.html#maxrowserror-how-can-i-plot-large-datasets